# dispatcher.useInsertionEffect is not a function (react 18.2 and react-dom 18.2)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, react-pdf, react-pdfrenderer

I'm trying to use the package react-pdf.

```
const SummaryTable = () => (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
        <Typography> Test</Typography>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );

return (
        <>
          <PDFDownloadLink document={<SummaryTable />} fileName="somename.pdf">
            {({ blob, url, loading, error }) =>
              loading ? "Loading document..." : "Download now!"
            }
          </PDFDownloadLink>
          <SummaryTable />
        </>
  );
```

Here's my package.json :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.4",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^3.1.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "firebase": "^9.22.1",
    "papaparse": "^5.4.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

When i try to display this page, i have
**dispatcher.useInsertionEffect is not a function**

The solution in the previous SO threads doesn't work, i'm already on react and react-dom 18.2.

Comment: In addition to the code posted above, may you post a codesandbox link as well?

Comment: I've encountered this issue as well. Any resolutions?

Comment: I'm not using this anymore.